# LINUX "No valid partition table was found on this device." + "Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!" + fdisk reads "7.3T" Size; How to fix?

Tags: linux, ext4, fdisk, parted, partition-table

Distro: Netrunner Blackbird (Debian)
I/O: Sata to USB cable

**KDE Parition Editor**: "No valid partition table was found on this device."

```
me@computer:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA LITEONIT LCT-128 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  269MB   268MB   primary  ext4         boot
 2      269MB   32.5GB  32.2GB  primary  ext4
 3      32.5GB  54.0GB  21.5GB  primary  ext4
 4      54.0GB  128GB   74.1GB  primary  ext4


Model: ATA ST1000LM049-2GH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  8591MB  8590MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      8591MB  17.2GB  8590MB  primary  ext4
 3      17.2GB  1000GB  983GB   primary  ext4


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel? i
Model: WDC WD10 02F9YZ-09H1JL1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      8389kB  8002GB  8002GB  primary
```

...

```
me@computer:~$ sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 244190646 sectors
Disk model: 02F9YZ-09H1JL1  
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x45b0734a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953523711 1953521664  7.3T 83 Linux
```

...

This:

```
me@computer:~$ sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdc > sdc-backup.txt
```

Gave me this as a text file in my home folder:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x45b0734a
device: /dev/sdc
unit: sectors

/dev/sdc1 : start=        2048, size=  1953521664, type=83
```

...

So, I'm not sure as to what exactly is going on here or how to fix it... I looked up the `sudo parted` error and found this:

https://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php

Looks to be the same issue (and it seems that finding this with gparted, instead of KDE's Partition Editor is irrelevant), but before I go making changes to a partition table, I want to be as careful as possible, because I REALLY can't lose the data on the HDD.

Any suggestions or know any specific fixes anyone can point me to?

I really appreciate all the help and let me know if you want me to run any other commands to post here.

Thanks all.

FYI: I installed `testdisk` and am running it now, if you need the outputs of that somewhere, let me know.

Update for "oldfred" to see by suggestion of the cli command recommended:

```
me@computer:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************


Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
1709333071 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sdc: 244190646 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: 02F9YZ-09H1JL1  
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F6F07956-BB67-4AB5-9DE6-67729F8EFB57
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 5
First usable sector is 6, last usable sector is 244190640
Partitions will be aligned on 256-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2042 sectors (8.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      1953523711   7.3 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem
```

Comment: It is showing logical/physical as 4k/4k and most systems are 512/4K. https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/ You also are using an older copy of fdisk & sfdisk as newer copies output more data to support newer gpt partitioned drives.

Comment: Do I need to change that? And if I do, will that corrupt the data?

Comment: Most likely that would be a total reformat. So refresh your normal backups before doing anything. I would see what this says, do not necessarily convert to gpt although if only LInux that is a choice. `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT

Comment: Ok, I put the output of that terminal command.

Comment: how do I convert back to mbr if need be?

Comment: You can totally repartition & reformat. Then restore data from backups. There is conversion that may work, but again backups required. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html Since it says invalid gpt and backup gpt partition table, was this converted from gpt to MBR by Windows? Leaving backup gpt partition table is a typical error created by Windows when it converts gpt to MBR.

Comment: No, I don't use Windows. Well, I use Windows in a VM hosted from Linux, but that's irrelevant, the VM is .vdi and it shares folders from the faulty hard drive, but that's all handled by the host to be able to be read by the Windows OS in the VM.

Also, I can't access the drive through even the command line and so, there is no way for me to make a backup before I reformat... any other suggestions? ** to be clear ** this IS my backup hard drive and my normal hard drive has lost it's data already.

Comment: Multipost of https://superuser.com/q/1513645/332907